# Can the type returned by std::bind be default-constructed?

Tags: c++, c++11, bind, typedef, default-constructor

I can `typedef` the return type of a `std::bind` expression, but apparently the compiler is not happy with me calling the default-constructor of this type. Instead, I have to pass the exact same arguments that I did to `std::bind` in the first place (cf below); why? Am I doing this wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

#define x_plus_one(T) std::bind<T>( f_plus<T>(), std::placeholders::_1, T(1) )

template <class T>
struct f_plus
{
    inline T operator() ( const T& a, const T& b ) const
        { return a + b; }
};

template <class T>
using x_plus_one_type = decltype( x_plus_one(T) );

int main()
{
    auto f = x_plus_one(double);
    std::cout<< f(3.2) << "\n";

    // auto g = x_plus_one_type<double>(); ==> fails, no matching constructor
    auto g = x_plus_one_type<double>( f_plus<double>(), std::placeholders::_1, 1 ); // but this works?!
    std::cout<< g(3.2) << "\n";
}
```

I also tried passing an `f_minus` function object, and swapping the placeholder and `1`, but the compiler doesn't like it, which really confuses me. The only little "hack" that worked was replacing `1` which `2`, which tells me that whatever the type returned by `bind` is, it doesn't copy the inputs. Why not? Is there a way to force the copy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Type returned by `std::bind` is unspecified. As such, it is unspecified if it can be constructed in any way other than by calling `std::bind`. You can use `std::unique_ptr` or `boost::optional` to have an unconstructed value.

Comment: Well, this is not ideal, but I guess it's the right answer, thanks.